# Convert any date string to current culture date format

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, culture

Suppose I have one datestring input i.e "30.03.2016" (i.e assuming here it may be any lanuage format)  but my current culture is United States. I want to convert the input to Windows saved locale setting culture. I am using below format for conversion,but gives me invalid datetime.

```
var myDateTimeValue = "30.03.2015";
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse(myDateTimeValue);
var dateingddmmyy = myDateTime.ToString(new CultureInfo("sv-SE"));
Console.Write(dateingddmmyy);
```

Please let me know how can I convert any type of date string to current culture format.

Comment: "Any language format" is problematic. Should "05/06/2016" be June 5th (as per UK format) or May 6th (as per US format)?

Comment: your code is running fine on my PC

Comment: @JonSkeet my requirementi "Any language format" is it possible to convert or not????

Comment: Not unambiguously, no. I've given an example where two language formats both give the same output for different inputs...

Answer (score 1):

The source date could be anything like:

- dd-mm-yyyy
- dd/mm/yyyy,
- mm-dd-yyyy,
- mm/dd/yyyy
- yyyy-MM-dd

I suggest you take a step back and explore what you are trying to solve in more details. Maybe you don't need to convert from any data format, maybe there is a way to provide such.

Comment: Thanks @David Rutkowski  just posted my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Below i have solved my issue   :**

```
string[] formats = {"M/d/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy",
                                "d/M/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                "yyyy/M/d", "yyyy/MM/dd",
                                "M-d-yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy",
                                "d-M-yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy",
                                "yyyy-M-d", "yyyy-MM-dd",
                                "M.d.yyyy", "MM.dd.yyyy",
                                "d.M.yyyy", "dd.MM.yyyy",
                                "yyyy.M.d", "yyyy.MM.dd",
                                "M,d,yyyy", "MM,dd,yyyy",
                                "d,M,yyyy", "dd,MM,yyyy",
                                "yyyy,M,d", "yyyy,MM,dd",
                                "M d yyyy", "MM dd yyyy",
                                "d M yyyy", "dd MM yyyy",
                                "yyyy M d", "yyyy MM dd"
                               };
                DateTime dateValue;

                    foreach (string dateStringFormat in formats)
                    {
                        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDateTime, dateStringFormat,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,
                                                   out dateValue))
                        {
                            return dateValue.ToShortDateString();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: What is someone will use custom date format which is not present in formats array?

Comment: only solution you have to add format in array first..i don't think so their is alternative of above solution..because if user enters any date then format is must that have to be specified in array so that casting is done on that basis.. @DawidRutkowski ..rest if you suggest anything better most welcome...

Comment: Why not to simply add validation to the field where user is supposed to type a date? Then you will be sure that the date will be always in the same  format.

Comment: Look my problem is not validation here ..my requirement is like user can enter any format date string...but i have to convert it according to windows local settings..So thats why format comes in to picture more..if validation is the only purpose then your suggestion is appropriate @DawidRutkowski